# How can I resample a subarea of an image for a viewport application?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV to implement an application that provides a 2D viewport that can be moved and resized over a larger image.

To do this I need to be able to take a subarea of my source image and render it to the ouput at subpixel accuracy. In effect, the operation is a combined crop and resize.

I could crop the image at subpixel accuracy using [getRectSubPix](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getrectsubpix) and then resize it to the resolution of my output viewport. However, this has a problem. As getRectSubPix returns an image at the same resolution as the source image, it constrains the viewport to sizes that have integer width and height in terms of the source image resolution. This is unacceptable in the application as we need to be able to zoom smoothly.

I could instead resize the image first to the same resolution as the ouputted viewport and then crop it. However, when dealing with a tiny viewport over a large image, this will require a lot of unnecessary work and space.

What I need is a combined process that both resizes and crops the image at the same time. Does anyone know of the easiest way to do this with Open CV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cv::remap](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#remap) was the function I was looking for. It allows you to sample each output pixel from a specified location in the source image, locations which you provide through a two channel matrix.

It's a bit more fiddly than a dedicated function but does the trick (for enlarging at least... `remap` cannot use `CV_INTER_AREA` for reductions requiring a bit of extra work to get good results in these cases).